# How do you get a scriptscriptstyle-sized prime?

Tags: symbols, fontsize, subscripts, superscripts

As you go from `\displaystyle` to `\scriptstyle` to `\scriptscriptstyle`, letters and numbers, for instance, shrink.  Weirdly, to my mind, the prime symbol (') shrinks from `\displaystyle` to `\scriptstyle`, but then is again the same size in `\scripstscriptstyle`.  For example:

```
\[
a {\scriptstyle a} {\scriptscriptstyle a} \quad
' {\scriptstyle '} {\scriptscriptstyle '} \quad
a' {\scriptstyle a'} {\scriptscriptstyle a'}
\]
```

[image: Various prime sizes]

The effect of this is that sometimes (eg in certain sub or superscripts or labels), primes look much too large relative to the surrounding symbols.

**How should one produce a properly scriptscriptstyle-sized prime symbol?**

Comment: The prime you get in displaystyle/textstyle is already in subscriptstyle: `'` stands for `^{\prime}`; thus you get a scriptscriptstyle prime in scriptstyle and the same in scriptscriptstyle.

Comment: @egreg: Okay, thanks, that explains why it is happening.  How do you obtain a prime symbol that is scaled down from scriptscriptstyle by the same amount that scriptscriptstyle is scaled down from scriptstyle, so that {\scriptscriptstyle a'} produces output that looks correct rather than misproportioned?

Comment: It's possible, but not with the `'` syntax.

Comment: Okay, great.  I'm not wedded to the `'` syntax.  What do you recommend instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `scalerel` package can do this.  I made the scriptscript prime equal to .6 the size of the script prime.  One invokes it as `\ssp{`*base*`}` to get *base*`'`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand\scale[2]{\vstretch{#1}{\hstretch{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\ssp[1]{#1^{\scale{.6}{\scriptstyle\prime}}}

\begin{document}

\[
a {\scriptstyle a} {\scriptscriptstyle a} \quad
' {\scriptstyle '} %{\scriptscriptstyle '} 
{\scriptscriptstyle \ssp{\rule{0ex}{1ex}}}
\quad
a' {\scriptstyle a'} %{\scriptscriptstyle a'}
{\scriptscriptstyle \ssp{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]